# How do I ignore negative numbers when finding the minimum in a group of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a': (1, 2, 'a'), 'b': (1, 2, 'b'), 'c': (2, 4, 'c'), 'd': (1, 3, 'd'), 'e': (0, 1, 'e'), 'f': (0, 1, 'f'), 'g': (1, 3, 'g'), 'h': (0, 1, 'h'), 'j': (1, 2, 'j'), 'i': (0, 1, 'i'), 'k': (-1, 0, 'k')}
```

And I want to find which one is the minimum of all the values in the dictionary. However, on the last key (k) there is a -1.

How can I ignore that key/value without removing it? Or is the only way to remove :

```
'k': (-1, 0, 'k')
```

and then use min().

**Here is my code:**

```
print(min(d.values()))
```

**Current output:**

```
(-1, 0, 'k')
```

**Expected output:**

```
(0, 1, 'e')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "filter" tuples that start with negatives out and not include them when you call `min`:

```
d = {'a': (1, 2, 'a'), 'b': (1, 2, 'b'), 'c': (2, 4, 'c'), 'd': (1, 3, 'd'), 'e': (0, 1, 'e'), 'f': (0, 1, 'f'), 'g': (1, 3, 'g'), 'h': (0, 1, 'h'), 'j': (1, 2, 'j'), 'i': (0, 1, 'i'), 'k': (-1, 0, 'k')}

print(min(tup for tup in d.values() if tup[0] >= 0))
```

Output:

```
(0, 1, 'e')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by passing in a `key` function to `min` that forces the negative values to rank higher:

```
min(d.values(), key=lambda x: (x[0]<0, x))
#(0, 1, 'e')
```

For the negative values, `x[0]<0` will be 1 so they will sort higher than the positive values. Finally for the positive values, `x` will be used to find the min.

Comment: This doesn't sort items lexicographically.

Comment: Ok then you can change it to `key = lambda x: (x[0]<0, x)`. It depends on what OP wants.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a quick and easy modification.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant is to use `filter` function:

```
min(filter(lambda x: x[0] >= 0, d.values()))
```